# How to hide certain rows in DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have datatables using ajax as data source, also I have an array contains several row_id , I would like to show rows which row_id is not in this array.

How can I do it?

I have search datatables doc, and tried many functions/callbacks, neither of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easily set up a [custom filter](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) that permanently exclude (or hide) certain rows after any criteria you want :

```
var excluded_row_ids = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43]

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
   //assuming the row_id is located in first column
   return (!~excluded_row_ids.indexOf(parseInt(data[0]))) 

   //or for example compare to dataIndex, i.e. original insert order
   //return (!~excluded_row_ids.indexOf(dataIndex))
})
```

If you for some reason want to include the excluded rows, simply remove the filter :

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop()
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/pcwf6tuh/**